# Turtles with size in Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I need to create turtles that have a certain dimension and check for overlap.
Since turtles per definition have no extension, I thought maybe the gis extension could be useful.

There is a way of associating an envelope with a turtle like

```
let gis:envelope-of self (list (xcor - 2 ) (xcor + 2) (ycor - 2) (ycor + 2))
```

But I don't know how to use this to draw the envelope and to check for overlaps.

Another way could be to give up the idea of one turtle having dimensions and to create a gis dataset from turtles by using

```
gis:turtle-dataset turtle-set
```

But I don't know how to create a polygon with this :-(

Any ideas?

Comment: I've never worked with extensions, but turtles have size. https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#size Is this what you mean?

Comment: Does the shape of the turtles matter? If they are circles for instance checking for overlap is not too hard.

Comment: I always tought the size was just for display, But I'll check this out.
And yes, the shape and size is important: This is the start of a work about house distributions, so I will have to map it to actual data. But you're right in that I could use the in-radius primitive if the shape would be a circle. I could however create a reporter and use it to check for overlap.

Comment: keep me in the loop if you have a nice solution. it is an interesting problem

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** for Seth's comment to make explicit the different approaches for circles and others.

If the turtles are circles, then there is an overlap if the sum of the sizes of the two turtles < distance between them / 2, using the `distance primitive` as in Seth's comment.

However, if you have squares or other shapes, then you will have to do some fancy stuff with `heading` and the various trigonometry functions, and will need the differences of positions in the x and y direction (differences in `xcor` and `ycor` respectively. Something like this will get you started:

```
to-report xdiff [ turt1 turt2 ]
  report [xcor] of turt1 - [xcor] of turt2
end
```

Comment: Your `find-distance` is just the same as the built in `distance` primitive — there's no need to do the math yourself, you can just write `[distance turt1] of turt2`. `distance` is better actually because it knows about both wrapping and non-wrapping worlds; your code only works in a non-wrapping world.

Comment: Thanks anyway for you reporter. In the moment I don't feel like constructing a reporter for this. I'm going to ask the guys who wrote the extension, if they could come up with s.th.
I'll keep you informed, however :-)

Comment: Well, one of the contributers is Seth Tissue :-)
Do you think this can be solved via the GIS extension?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I took an easy way out: 
Since my objects don't have to move, I use adjacent patches to form a block of the needed size. Before I occupy a new patch, I check if it is already used and if so I delete all newly occupied patches.
Not very versatily, but it does the job for me so far.